# Print output value from specific input values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

The output of my neural network is stored in the dictionary `outvar`. The dictionary has one key and a large number of values associated with it. I am plotting it against a range of a and b values as shown below. How do I print out an `outvar` value when given a specific a and b value?

Below is a section of my code that was used in building a neural network

```
 def __call__(self, invar, outvar):
        "custom function for plotting inferencer data"
        ndim = len(invar)
        extent, outvar = self._interpolate_2D(100, invar, outvar) #100 vaue should match linspace values
        a = np.linspace(0, 1, 100) #z length
        b = np.linspace(0, 4, 100) #time
        # make plots
        dims = list(invar.keys())
        fs = []

        for k in outvar:
            f = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
            plt.pcolor(a, b, outvar[k].T, vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0) # origin="lower", extent=extent)
            plt.xlabel(dims[0])
            plt.ylabel(dims[1])
            plt.colorbar()
            plt.title("Concentration Profile")
            #plt.suptitle("Concentration Profile")
            plt.tight_layout()
            fs.append((f, k))
            #print(outvar) #outvar is a dict
        return fs
```

Answer (score 0):

To print dicts I usually use

> json.dumps(outvar, indent=2)

If you want to save the dict would recomend to use [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage):

> json.dump(outvar, [file_path].json)

If you want to get fancy you can define the [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) by cli

> python3 [yourscript].py >[file_path].json

and inside the script:

> json.dump(outvar, sys.stdout)